# How to read multiple nested nodes from similar elements in an XML using XPath?

Tags: xml, xpath, jasper-reports, xpath-2.0

I'm trying to use an XPath expression in Jaspersoft Studio to fetch the following fields from an XML that has multiple `<cac: InvoiceLine>` elements. Something like this from each InvoiceLine element.

| cbc:Name | cbc:Description | cbc:InvoicedQuantity | cbc:LineExtensionAmount | cbc:PriceAmount |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Item One | First Item Description | 4 | 168.26 | 142.06 |
| Item Two | Second Item Description | 1 | 42.06 | 92.06 |

**Xml:**

```
 </Invoice>
  <Other elements>
  ...
  <Other elements>
   <cac:InvoiceLine>
            <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="5B">4</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
            <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="NZD">168.26</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
            <cac:Item>
                <cbc:Name>Item One</cbc:Name>
                <cbc:Description>First Item Description</cbc:Description>                   
            </cac:Item>
            <cac:Price>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="NZD">142.06</cbc:PriceAmount>
            </cac:Price>
   </cac:InvoiceLine>
        <cac:InvoiceLine>
            <cbc:InvoicedQuantity unitCode="5B">1</cbc:InvoicedQuantity>
            <cbc:LineExtensionAmount currencyID="NZD">42.06</cbc:LineExtensionAmount>
            <cac:Item>
                <cbc:Name>Item Two</cbc:Name>
                <cbc:Description>Second Item Description</cbc:Description>
            </cac:Item>
            <cac:Price>
                <cbc:PriceAmount currencyID="NZD">92.06</cbc:PriceAmount>
            </cac:Price>
        </cac:InvoiceLine>
 </Invoice>
```

What do I need to add to my Xpath expression to get each row of data with those fields?

What I'm initially tried is `/*[local-name()='Invoice']/cac:InvoiceLine` but it's only going as far as fetching cbc:invoicedQantity and cbc:LineExtensionAmount from each InvoiceLine element.

Then I tried this

```
 /*[local-name()='Invoice']/cac:InvoiceLine |  
 /*[local-name()='Invoice']/cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Item |    
 /*[local-name()='Invoice']/cac:InvoiceLine/cac:Price
```

Doing this gives separate rows of records for each expression. What I am looking for is a union of these expressions as one record

Comment: Hi USQ91 I added a duplicate which I have answered, you need to use your first expression and then reference the cac:Item etc as indicated in duplicate, hence in field declaration you drill down to the value